# Sitecore 8.1 - Integrate FED work to Sitecore Solution

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

We have a team of 9 developers below :

1. 2 x Designers
2. 2 x FED
3. 5 x Sitecore/MVC Developers

We use VSO TFS for code repository.

FEDs do not have any idea of how Sitecore works let alone the Visual Studio Solution.

One of the challenge we are facing at the moment is seamless process for integration for FE work on to our Sitecore Solution.

One option is to create a FED folder our visual studio and use Grunt Task to generate CSS/JS and move them to our VS Solution.

I think this is a common issue and would appreciate if you could share the pattern you've established which has worked seamlessly.

Thanks.

Comment: FED are usually happy when they do not have to work in VS, and a Grunt task as post build step works just fine. I also use it in a number of projects, and let FE decide which tooling they use.

Comment: This is my personal opinion, but why leave everything to automated processes? Back-end developers love to automated everything, but is it really necessary always? Practically it would be better to let your front-end developers updated their own separate repository over SVN or some sort of source control and let them keep it updated. Then back-end developers only keep their separate repository updated by manually copy-pasting from FEDs repo

Comment: @Behrooz Because automation is faster, eliminates manual error, and enables teams to continuously integrate, test, and deliver their software?

Comment: Given team and project size, manual process can introduce regression.

Comment: Depends on the point in the project. A mock site outside of Sitecore with  static HTML + CSS/JS + Gulp/Grunt works great if you haven't started development. Otherwise, we setup a Sitecore instance for FEDs with Gulp/Grunt because regression is a potential problem if they can't consume the whole site.